# Inverse question

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

If I have $a(x)=2x$ and $b(x)=x+1$. I am trying to find $ (a \circ b)^{-1}(x+3)$. However I have 2 different ways:

1. Let $c(x)=a(b(x+3))=2x+8$. We have $c^{-1}(x)=\frac{x-8}{2}$. The answer is $\frac{x-8}{2}$ here
2. Let $d(x)=a(b(x))=2x+2$. We have $d^{-1}(x)=\frac{x-2}{2}$. So $g(x)=d^{-1}(x+3)=\frac{x+1}{2}$. The answer is $\frac{x+1}{2}$ here

I see that the first one is correct, but I don't understand why is the second way wrong. Is it that $(a(b(x+3))^{-1}$ different from $(a \circ b)^{-1}(x+3)$?

Comment: The first way is wrong. The second way is correct. Your are taking the inverse of $a\circ b$ and putting $y=x+3$ in as input.  You are not trying to find the inverse of $c(x)=a(b(x+3))$.

Comment: ANd yes,  $(a(b(x+3))^{-1}$ is *UTTERLY* different than $(a\circ b)^{-1}(x+3)$.

Comment: @fleablood Ok, Thank you! I suspected that at first, but was unsure.

Comment: $a(b(x)) = 2x+2$ and so $(a\circ b)^{-1}(x)=\frac {x-2}2$. so If $y = x+3$ then $(a\circ b)^{-1}(y)= (a\circ b)^{-1}(x+3)$ and $(a\circ b)^{-1}(y)=\frac {y-2}2=\frac {x+3-2}2=\frac {x+1}2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x+3$. Then your defined functions are $$c(x) = d(x+3) = d(f(x))$$

Taking the inverse, $$c^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(d^{-1}(x)) = d^{-1}(x) - 3$$

You need to apply the inverse of $d(x+3)$ as a nested function, but you took the inverse of $d(x)$ by itself, and then plugged in $x+3$ as the argument. Your calculation needs to include an inverse to the $+3$. Therefore the answer you are looking for in the end is not $$d^{-1}(x+3) = \tfrac{x+1}{2}$$ but rather $$d^{-1}(x) - 3 = \tfrac{x-2}{2} - 3 = \tfrac{x-8}{2}$$

Comment: But nowhere is anyone asking for the inverse of $c(x) = d(x+3)$.  The are only asking for the inverse of $d(x) =a(b(x))$ evaluated with input of $x+3$.  The second method is completely correct and the first is completely wrong.

Comment: Comparing the first method to the second method, $c(x) = d(x+3)$. In taking the inverse of either the first or second method, the correct answer is found regardless. However, the inverse of the second method was taken incorrectly in the original post.